# Dynamic collection in FlipView

Tags: wpf, winrt-xaml, flipview

Is it possible to load next\previous item in [FlipView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.flipview.ASPx) on demand? Lets say I display an Item and will download next one only when user press left\right button?

FlipView has Items and ItemsSource properties, but in such case I have to specify full collection of items at once instead of downloading them one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `ObservableCollection` for the `ItemsSource` property on your `FlipView`.
You can subscribe to the `SelectionChanged` event on your `FlipView`:

```
private void FlipView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //
}
```

In this handler, you can get the current index and decide if you have to load the next item or not (i.e. if the index is `Count - 1` of your collection).

Beware that when adding an item to the collection, the event will fire and your handler will be called.